# How to scroll to anchor point in responsive website?

Tags: javascript, scroll, responsive-design, percentage, anchorpoint

I'm making a portfolio website that contains a simple dropdownlist and one big GIF image in a div (10659px × 6850px). As I intended, when you make selections from the list, you jump to certain anchor points on the page using a simple javascript that's being activated onChange.

The html:

```
<div id="background">
<img src="img/background.gif" width="10659" /></div>

<select id="dropdownlist" onChange="jumpScroll(this.value);">
<option  alt="selected works" value="0">Selected works:</option>
<option  alt="work 1" value="1">Work 1</option>
<option  alt="work 2" value="2">Work 2</option>
<option  alt="work 3" value="3">Work 3</option>
</select>
```

The javascript:

```
function jumpScroll(inobj) {


switch (inobj) {

case "1":
    window.scroll(1938,2740);
    break;

case "2":
    window.scroll(7753,5483);
    break;

case "3":
    window.scroll(0,1369);
    break;

    default:
    break;
}
}
```

My problem: I want to make the website responsive so that the image has the same ratio on every screen. The width of the image for example will then become 550% instead of 10659px. But then the set anchor points start to move and mismatch, of course. Is there a way to solve this? Maybe to use a javascript or jQuery that uses relative values instead of fixed pixels? Or to cut up the image and make various ID's to refer to? Any tips or answers will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you scrolling to a background image and not to content? This would seem to create some potential usability issues.

Comment: When using anchor points, the principle is the same, right? I could imagine using various ID's in the content to refer to in the javascript, but wouldn't know how to code that.

Comment: You really shouldn't have the whole content of your site be an image, for a few reasons, usability, seo, loading time etc.

Comment: If your content was actually content, you could easily ask jQuery to give them their positions, and then scroll to them. If you want to keep using an image, then you need to determine the position in `%` of your content sections relative to the top left of the image, then, before scrolling, ask jQuery the width of the image, and compute the location in pixels.

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me. I could get rid of the image and make content, but then still wouldn't know how to make the jQuery do the scrolling. Any tips, links or references?

Comment: I have a working jQuery posted as answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok a friend helped me out, here's the jQuery that does what I want. I don't use one background image anymore but multiple div's, and the jQuery scrolls to their ID's.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dropdownlist").on('change',function(){
    var project = "#" + $(this).val();
    $.scrollTo($(project), 1000);
});
});
```

Principle:

```
<div id="workone">Work 1 content</div>
<div id="worktwo">Work 2 content</div>
<div id="workthree">Work 3 content</div>

<select id="dropdownlist">
<option value="workone">Work 1</option>
<option value="worktwo">Work 2</option>
<option value="workthree">Work 3</option>
</select>
```

Link to the scrollto jQuery download: http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js

Thanks for the advices!

Comment: Note the correct download link is https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases

Answer (score 1):

I see you used and recommend my plugin. I'd like to point out that link you provided leads to an old version of the plugin.
I moved out of Google Code a long time ago to Github.
You (and others) should get the latest version from the releases page:

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases

Cheers